# libreadline undefined symbol: PC in bash when using | bc -l

Tags: bash, bc, libreadline

I am connecting by `ssh` to another machine to execute a bash script, whose problematic part is the following:

```
fkeypar "ex1.fef[1]" TSTARTI         #### fkeypar is an external command to get some values to assign to the subsequent variables
t0i="$(expr $(pget fkeypar value) - 11544)"                                          
fkeypar "ex1lc.fits[2]" TELAPSE
lengthini=`pget fkeypar value`
fkeypar "ex7lc.fits[2]" TSTOP
lengthfin=`pget fkeypar value`
fkeypar "ex1lc.fits[2]" TSTART      
ijd=`pget fkeypar value`

i=$(echo "($ijd - $t0i) / $period + 1" | bc -l | sed 's/\..*//')
ifin=$(echo "($lengthfin - $ijd)/$period + 1" | bc -l | sed 's/\..*//')
echo "($ijd - $t0i) / $period + 1" | bc

for ((n=$i; n<=$ifin; n++))
do
   ...
```

This returns the following errors:

```
bc: symbol lookup error: /science/heasoft-6.14/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-libc2.9/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC
bc: symbol lookup error: /science/heasoft-6.14/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-libc2.9/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC
bc: symbol lookup error: /science/heasoft-6.14/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-libc2.9/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC
./script: line 39: ((: n=: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")
```

Googling A LOT, I found that i very related with these "bugs":
https://science.nrao.edu/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=75

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=162023

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31143/libreadline-so-6

I don't have any idea on how to fix it, without trying random things. Any help really appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that, in my many trials, ssh-ing many times, I managed somehow to do not get the error and run the script, with the same syntax as reported in the question. At that moment, I thought it was a syntax problem, but then the error appeared again at consequent ssh-ings.

EDIT2: IT doesn't matter what version of `heasoft` I load, the error always appears for the `heasoft-6.14` version. I think this is related to a possible fix.

Comment: This isn't specific to the script at all -- it's a problem with the copy of bc on that specific machine. Get your sysadmin to help; it's not something we can guide you through here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I see. What do you mean "Get your sysadmin to help"? Is it a file or a person?

Comment: Your system administrator -- a person.

Answer (score 2):

Most of this is a problem we can't help with -- someone with administrative rights to recompile `bc` (or, better, someone who knows *why* you're not doing the sane thing and using an OS-vendor-provided version) would need to fix it. (This may be as simple as renaming the `bc` under `/science/heasoft-6.14` out of the way, and allowing a vendor-provided implementation in the PATH to be used instead).

That said, if you're only doing integer math, there's no reason for this script to use bc at all:

```
i=$(( (idj - t01) / period + 1 ))
ifin=$(( ( lengthfin - ijd ) / period + 1 ))
echo "$(( ( ijd - t01 ) / period + 1 ))"
```

The error you have on line 39 is a consequence of these bugs in `bc` -- the script expects `i` to contain a number, but it's an empty string, so `n=$i` can't evaluate `"$i"` as a number, so it fails. In a math context (which is what the double parenthesis create), `i` evaluates as 0 if the variable is undefined, but `$i` causes an error in that same scenario; which of these to use depends on your desired behavior. If you want an error when a variable is undefined, use `$varname` inside of `(( ))`; if you want the script to continue with a value of 0, use bare `varname`.

Comment: Did you mean `i=$(( ($idj - $t0i) / $period + 1 ))` ?

Comment: No, I didn't. The expansion operator is optional inside of a math context; I explain this in detail in my answer.

Comment: I see, the edit came later. However, I forgot to mention that, in my many trials, ssh-ing many times, I managed somehow to do not get the error and run the script, with the same syntax as reported in the question. At that moment, I thought it was a syntax problem, but then the error appeared again at consequent ssh-ings.

Comment: ...in that case, I'm guessing that the system you're using has some environment settings -- such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -- that paper over the problem, and that you occasionally managed to get in a way that avoided getting those configured. (It could also be that in some use cases you don't have the `PATH` specifying the use of that non-default toolchain; having no access to the system we can only speculate, and it's not a programming problem anyhow regardless). Still, that's a question for the people who set up and maintain the system, not for the StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have any idea on how to fix it, without trying random things. Any help really appreciated.

The recipe to build Readline on your platform is broken. Here are the technical details... The shared object has missing symbols, which is kind of OK:

```
$ ldd -r -d /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffea672a000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fec922eb000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fec92521000)
undefined symbol: UP    (/usr/local/lib/libreadline.so)
undefined symbol: PC    (/usr/local/lib/libreadline.so)
undefined symbol: BC    (/usr/local/lib/libreadline.so)
undefined symbol: tputs (/usr/local/lib/libreadline.so)
undefined symbol: tgoto (/usr/local/lib/libreadline.so)
undefined symbol: tgetflag      (/usr/local/lib/libreadline.so)
undefined symbol: tgetent       (/usr/local/lib/libreadline.so)
undefined symbol: tgetnum       (/usr/local/lib/libreadline.so)
undefined symbol: tgetstr       (/usr/local/lib/libreadline.so)
```

In reality, I think the build should fail because of the missing symbols. But the maintainer thinks otherwise and prefers to spread his pain and suffering to users of his library.

The missing symbols are part of Ncurses and Terminfo, but the link library is missing. That's not OK. The link library should be something like `libtinfo.so` or `libtinfow.so` but it is missing:

```
$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd535cb000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3a5183c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3a520b5000)
```

And here is where `UP`, `PC` and friends are located:

```
$ nm -D /usr/local/lib/libtinfow.so | grep -E 'UP|PC'
000000000023797e B PC
0000000000237968 B UP
```

You are supposed to be able to add `-ltinfo` or `-ltinfow` to your `LIBS`/`LDLIBS` during Readline configure but that does not work. Adding `-ltinfo` or `-ltinfow` is ignored.

The fix in practice is to patch the Readline makefile, and then build Ncurses and Readline from sources.

Here's what the Readline patch looks like. The patch was created with `diff -u`:

```
--- shlib/Makefile.in
+++ shlib/Makefile.in
@@ -174,11 +174,11 @@
 
 $(SHARED_READLINE):    $(SHARED_OBJ)
    $(RM) $@
-   $(SHOBJ_LD) ${SHOBJ_LDFLAGS} ${SHLIB_XLDFLAGS} -o $@ $(SHARED_OBJ) $(SHLIB_LIBS)
+   $(SHOBJ_LD) ${SHOBJ_LDFLAGS} ${SHLIB_XLDFLAGS} -o $@ $(SHARED_OBJ) $(SHLIB_LIBS) -ltinfo
 
 $(SHARED_HISTORY): $(SHARED_HISTOBJ) xmalloc.so xfree.so
    $(RM) $@
-   $(SHOBJ_LD) ${SHOBJ_LDFLAGS} ${SHLIB_XLDFLAGS} -o $@ $(SHARED_HISTOBJ) xmalloc.so xfree.so $(SHLIB_LIBS)
+   $(SHOBJ_LD) ${SHOBJ_LDFLAGS} ${SHLIB_XLDFLAGS} -o $@ $(SHARED_HISTOBJ) xmalloc.so xfree.so $(SHLIB_LIBS) -ltinfo
 
 # Since tilde.c is shared between readline and bash, make sure we compile 
 # it with the right flags when it's built as part of readline
```

Once you fix the makefile and build Ncurses and Readline, your link libraries will include `libtinfo.so`. Shit will no longer be broken. Notice `libtinfo.so` is linked below.

```
$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd535cb000)
        libtinfow.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/libtinfow.so.6 (0x00007f3a51c2d000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3a5183c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3a520b5000)
```

Now, it can be tricky to configure Ncurses properly. That's because there's a non-wide and wide version of all the libraries. There's something like 6 of them in Ncurses:

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/lib*w\.so*
/usr/local/lib/libformw.so         /usr/local/lib/libncursesw.so.6
/usr/local/lib/libformw.so.6       /usr/local/lib/libncurses++w.so.6.1
/usr/local/lib/libformw.so.6.1     /usr/local/lib/libncursesw.so.6.1
/usr/local/lib/libmenuw.so         /usr/local/lib/libpanelw.so
/usr/local/lib/libmenuw.so.6       /usr/local/lib/libpanelw.so.6
/usr/local/lib/libmenuw.so.6.1     /usr/local/lib/libpanelw.so.6.1
/usr/local/lib/libncurses++w.so    /usr/local/lib/libtinfow.so
/usr/local/lib/libncursesw.so      /usr/local/lib/libtinfow.so.6
/usr/local/lib/libncurses++w.so.6  /usr/local/lib/libtinfow.so.6.1
```

I build the ***wide*** versions of Ncurses by using the configure option `--enable-widec`. `--enable-widec` is [described as](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter08/ncurses.html):

> This switch causes wide-character libraries (e.g., libncursesw.so.6.2)
> to be built instead of normal ones (e.g., libncurses.so.6.2). These
> wide-character libraries are usable in both multibyte and traditional
> 8-bit locales, while normal libraries work properly only in 8-bit
> locales. Wide-character and normal libraries are source-compatible,
> but not binary-compatible.

If you configure Ncurses with `--enable-widec`, then you use `libtinfow.so` as a link library for Readline. If you use the non-wide version, then you use `libtinfo.so` as a link library for Readline.

If you configure Ncurses with `--enable-widec`, then you should configure your wide Readline with `--enable-multibyte`. If you build Bash from sources and use your wide Readline, then you should configure Bash with `--enable-multibyte`. You have to pay attention to the details...

And no, the different flags for the same option -- `--enable-widec` and `--enable-multibyte` -- is correct. Why be consistent when you can add confusion?

---

You can thank the fellow who maintains Ncurses and Readline for this mess. He does not follow standard GNU workflows or Linux best practices. I despise working with the crap he maintains. You will waste hours trying to figure out how to do something that should be simple, like which options to use, or getting Readline to use the proper link library, or getting a dependency like BC or OpenLDAP to build properly.

Another gem is the memory leaks. If you have the misfortune of needing this on Android then you can count on resource exhaustion because the libraries leak so much memory. Android via JNI will load and unload the shared objects thousands of times and you will be out of memory due to the accumulated memory leaks.

Finally, there is no public repo for Ncurses and Readline. There is no way to make a pull request or offer patches against his sources. His idea of a `git pull` is this crap: [Applying Patches](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#applying_patches).